# Is there a way to program to discover sites transmitting user/pass in plaintext (Not using SSL) for penetration testing?

Tags: tls, penetration-test

I have a CSV/Excel file which in which I want to test out the links which do not have SSL but ask for Username / Password. Is there a program which determines if each site on a list encrypts its login information as it is being sent?

Comment: Your question is vague,  what do you want to test exactly, is it an web server, ftp, mail ..etc?

Comment: THey all are webservers. They may have username\password field inline or as a popup. Mostly they wont have a username\password field. I want to check throughout the list of domain names, which ones don't have SSL, but still have a username/password form on the page

Comment: I would write bash / perl script to run in a for loop against list of your servers, and scan for port 443, and with curl grep for username / password in the page. will that work?

Comment: Yup, that should work. Not very adept with Perl, that's why was looking some ready made solution

Comment: Is your list a list of actual login pages (like this one: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1), or just a list of sites (like this one: https://www.google.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use a packet sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to observe the contents of the data packets as they travel between the website of interest and your computer.

Login using a unique string as the password, and search in Wireshark to find that string. It doesn't matter if it's the actual password or not, just as long as it is sent to the server.

If you are able to see that unique string in Wireshark, that must mean the password is being transmitted in the clear - i.e. over HTTP.

Comment: Rather than the packet sniffer approach, I have a huge list of sites. Individually inspecting packets is extremely resource intensive, Anyway I can do that automatically by piping in the list to some software which checks for SSL?

Comment: Using a search function is not comparable to "individually inspecting packets". It would probably take some time to build something to automate the process - I very much doubt if any pre-built tool to do that exists.

Answer (score 0):

You do it more-or-less exactly as you might think you'd do it. You watch the traffic in flight and look for keywords or other indicators of passwords being transmitted. The word "password" is pretty much a dead-giveaway. Commonly-used passwords (like "123456") are also something of a smoking gun. If you know what protocol is being used (e.g. POP3, SMTP, etc.) then you just decode the protocol and look for the password field.

Can this be automated? *Yep.* Has someone else done the work for you? *Nope.*

Useful tools in this pursuit include `libpcap`, `tcpdump`, `tshark`, `ngrep`, `tcpflow`, and perhaps a few others.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a thought but if you have a list of sites you want to go through, how about crawling all of them and "grep" for login form which points to http addresses?